# Open xdg-open to download files not working on google-chrome

Tags: chrome, xdg-open

I am having google-chrome(69.0.3497.100) on Debian Stretch, whenever I try to download some files by clicking on the download link there will a popup `Open xdg-open` and when I click on yes option nothing happens. I am unable to download anything on it. However when I use the same link in firefox then it downloads.

I think I need to add or update some entry in `/usr/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list` but I don't know what to add?

However google-chrome is the default browser to open links because when I type in terminal `xdg-open http://google.com` then this link will open in google-chrome.

**Update** I upgraded to `70.0.3538.77` but still same problem.

Comment: Are you unable to download *any* file type from any site with Chrome, or just *some* files of specific types? Did you experience this same issue with other (previous) Chrome versions?

Comment: @fra-san I am unable to download some files only. I am experiencing it first time.

Comment: @fra-san it happened suddenly after I started using torrent, because for torrent magnetic links it ask for `xdg-open` and it works fine for torrent links as it opens `qbittorrent` there.

Comment: You should check the output of `xdg-mime query default your-mime-type`. It should give you a `.desktop` file that tells you which application will be used. You can find the MIME type of a specific file with `xdg-mime query filetype /path/to/file`.

Comment: @fra-san thanks but the problem is I don't know what is mime-type for download links. So how to check?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused since there is no MIME type for "download links". But there are URI scheme handlers: for checking how magnet links are handled you can use `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet`. For torrent files: `xdg-mime query default application/x-bittorrent`.